# defining empty data frame with string columns and numeric columns and then adding values later

Tags: r, string, csv, dataframe, numbers

I am trying to define a data frame initially and then add rows using rbind one by one later. My problem is that in the following definition of `result`, I want humanReplicate, ratReplicate to be in string format and other columns to be in numeric format.

```
result <- data.frame(humanReplicate = "human_replicate",  ratReplicate = "rat_replicate",
     pvalue = "p-value", alternative = "alternative_hypothesis", Conf.int1 = "conf.int1", 
    Conf.int2 ="conf.int2", oddratio = "Odd_Ratio")
```

Then, I am currently adding new rows (which are results of a Fisher's test) in the following way :

```
newLine <- data.frame(t(c(humanReplicate = humanReplicateName,
 ratReplicate = ratReplicateName, pvalue = fisherTest$p, 
 alternative = fisherTest$alternative, Conf.int1 = fisherTest$conf.int[1],
 Conf.int2 =fisherTest$conf.int[2],  oddratio = fisherTest$estimate[[1]])))
result <-rbind(result,newLine)
```

Here all the values of the `fisherTest$X` is numeric. `humanReplicateName` and `ratReplicateName` are strings. But if I define result in the above way and then define newLine in this way then all the columns of the data frame becomes string. I understand when I define result here, I am making all of them string. But if I want to make it mixture of string and number, how should I define it?

My final goal is to get `result` as `csv` file and I am doing the following to do this:

```
write.table(result, file = "newData4.csv", row.names = FALSE, append = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

Comment: You should not be building data.frames row-by-row. This is not a good practice. You should collect all your data and turn it onto a data.frame at the very end (for reasons such as the one you are experiencing). There is no way to get a mixture of strings and numbers in a single column of a data.frame. All items in a column must be the same type. It seems like you just want a header row. As long as your columns have names, `col.names=` will put them on the first line. No need to have them *in* the data.frame.

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, I didn't mean I want a column of different types. I am trying to define result that can have columns of different types. ie column 1 is column of strings, whereas column 2 is of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the concatenate function `c()`. You do not need it as well as the `t`function. Indeed

```
tmp  <- data.frame(t(c("test" = 2,"human" = "Paul")))
```

apparently gives the same than this line

```
    tmp2  <- data.frame("test" = 2,"human" = "Paul")

> tmp
  test human
1    2  Paul

> tmp2
  test human
1    2  Paul
```

but

```
> tmp$test
test 
   2 
Levels: 2
> tmp2$test
[1] 2
```

and

```
> is.numeric(tmp$test)
[1] FALSE
> is.numeric(tmp2$test)
[1] TRUE
```

What happens is that with `c` first you make 1 vector, and mixing text and numeric is interpreted as a vector of factors, while with the directly call to `dataframe` you fill two different and indipendent columns